# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming

trying to upload file using apache file upload, but getting this error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

it was working yesterday, but today it is not working

Comment: One of the possibility is server can be down

Comment: Please elaborate, what kind of netwrok environment you are using, FTP, RMI, Web server etc?\, and add more detail arond what exactly you are doing?

Comment: @upog this server accept app port, server may be still running, but the port was change.

Comment: try to check if the server is open or not.you can check in windows command prompt by typeing netstat -a

Comment: In any case this is not a Java-related problem.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

Either the firewall configuration (by which I mean port forwarding, not access rules) has changed or the server process isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a locally hosted server. make sure the correct port is forwarded for the correct IPV4, they change often and without much reason.